# How to push different combos of elements into a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

The question I am trying to answer is: Combos of Any length

Modify this function so that it returns all combinations of the elements of arr as an array of arrays. Use Recursion!

This is what I have so far:

```js
function getAllCombos(arr, newArr = []) {
  if (arr[0] === undefined) return newArr
  newArr.push(arr)
  return getAllCombos(arr.slice(1), newArr)
}

console.log(getAllCombos(['a', 'b']));
console.log(getAllCombos(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

it gives me this result:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['b']]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']]
```

I am looking to get this result:

```
[['a','b'], ['a'], ['b'], []]
 [['a', 'b', 'c'],['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['b'], ['c'], [],]
```

How do I iterate through the array getting different combos? While also not repeating arrays that have already been pushed?
Here are the test cases:

```
console.log(getAllCombos(['a', 'b'])); 
console.log(getAllCombos(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

Comment: Consider starting with the empty array and building, rather than starting with the full array and slicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer

---

```js
const getAllCombosShort= array => array.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.flatMap(e => [e, [...e, curr]]), [[]])
console.log(getAllCombosShort(['a','b','c']));
```

#### Detailed answer

---

##### How recursion is structured

Recursion implies structuring your solution in three steps:

- Base Case: All the combos of an empty array is simply an array with an empty array inside.
- Induction Hypothesis (I.H.): Suppose it's known how to get all the combos for any array of length n-1.
- General Case (G.C.): Proof that you can solve for any array of length n using previous step.

##### How to construct a recursive algorithm

The key to reach the solution `S` through recursion is to find out how to extend the truth from I.H. to G.C.

> Assume that you give some arbitrary input to one of your best friends and, in return, he gives you the solution `S'` for the problem. However, as he doesn't want to give the solution `S` to you on a silver plate, he accepted to do all the part of the work which have *one unit less* than the original input.

With his solution `S'` in hands you're not only able to solve the problem with the complete input, but also construct the algorithm naturally.

For instance, `['a','b', 'c']`

- Give him `['b', 'c']` and get:

```
[ ['b','c'], ['b'], ['c'], [] ]
```

- For each element of it, create a new element which contains itself plus `'a'` and push it to **his** solution array, i.e.:

```
[     ['b','c'],     ['b'],     ['c'],   []  ,
  ['a','b','c'], ['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['a'] ]
```

##### Pseudocode

```
algorithm allCombos
  input: array of length n
  output: array of all combinations
   
if array is empty
       return an array with empty inside
head := head(array) -- head
tail := tail(array)
friend := allCombos(tail) -- your friend knows how to solve for one smaller
for each element of friends do
    new_elem := [...element, head]
    friend.push(new_elem)
return friend
```

##### Correspondent in Javascript:

```js
function getAllCombos(array) {
  if (array && array.length === 0) return [[]]
  let head = array[0]
  let tail = array.slice(1)
  friend = getAllCombos(tail)
  friend.forEach(elem => friend.push([head, ...elem]))
  return friend
}

console.log(getAllCombos(['a','b']))
console.log(getAllCombos(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```